# What is the point of 10k users seeing deleted stuff?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

I know that 10k users are able to see deleted questions but what's the point of that?

A question is deleted because it is low-quality, off-topic or badly recieved. I guess the reason behind this is because the question should not be seen by new users because they can be misled about what is the correct style of a good question. Also, these "trash" should not be floating around everywhere, right?

Now you give the 10k users the privilage to view deleted questions. That kind of makes them "not deleted". They must be still in the database! Furthermore, if I were a 10k user, why would I bother to read deleted posts? They are bad anyways. And obviously I would not be curious to see how bad they are.

Comment: 10k users can vote to UN-delete posts if they disagree with their deletion.

Comment: That's so you can enjoy the drama you would otherwise be missing.  Here's an example of someone butthurt that they've been programming for 30 years, but they can't manage to get 50 rep to comment http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309212/software-developer-with-30-years-of-experience-not-allowed-to-comment-because-t Now, you won't be able to savor the sweet, sweet fanny pain laced with a lovely compote of passive-aggressive whingeing.  But I can.  Sweetly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Sometimes the mob gets it wrong.

Deleting content is something that should be done under the most extreme cases; that is, the content on the site would be *more* harmful if it were undeleted.

Allowing a 10K user to see posts like that allow them to step in and cast a vote to reverse the decision in case it truly was in error.

> That kind of makes them "not deleted". They must be still in the database!

The term is [soft deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378331/physical-vs-logical-soft-delete-of-database-record).  It means that the data is still around in case it needs to be audited, but isn't generally visible to the public.

Comment: Generally, deleting data isn't something you want to do, regardless; space is cheap enough that just hiding it tends to pay off much more in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

Just because a post happens to be deleted doesn't imply it's was no good, users who have over 10K reputation are allowed to cast an *un-delete* vote if they believe the question should not of been removed. With enough votes this will restore the question.

Also it is actually rare for items that where "removed" to actually be deleted from the database right away, mainly because by design we do not trust our users. Basically meaning when you develop a website on you try your best to protect the user from themselves. So if they removed something by mistake it can retrieved (*restored*) it in some way.

Answer (score 3):

Its mentioned in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) as well:

> - Make sure what is being deleted should have been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community and/or moderator team.
> - Watch for signs of abuse being obscured by deletion.

Can be used to recover correct and useful answers that were deleted in the past.