# Change the stigma regarding signposts

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, signpost-questions

Plenty of Stack Overflow users have told me over the years that having great signposts is a sought outcome because it helps researchers (and search engines) to find the desired content.  However, for as long as I can remember, there has always been the underlying stigma that duplicate questions are pure redundant noise.

I am personally guilty of believing (for years) that all duplicates are deadweight. When I see a new question that has been asked before, I race to hammer it closed, downvote it, and seek its urgent deletion.

If this stigma is to change, we need to define what a good signpost looks like, potentially disincentivize answering questions which should only serve as signposts, and (most challengingly) convince curators that signposts are good.

1. What is a good signpost?

   - It should contain plenty of searchable keywords both in the title and in the question body (after all, its sole mission is to grab eyeballs),
   - contain a crystal clear [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and
   - represent a distinct situation not previously well-represented by another question and
   - it doesn't necessarily need a coding attempt, but proof of research would be favored.
2. How can answering signposts be disincentivized?

   - I am open to all suggestions on this matter, but my initial thought is to disable rep gains/losses on all answers from the moment that a question is closed as a duplicate (Resolved elsewhere). If the page is later reopened, rep can be gained/lost from that point, but no retrospective rep loading would apply. Regardless of the question's open/close status, up/downvotes would affect scores and ordering as usual.
   - The reason that some users seek the deletion of signposts is to prevent answerers from profiting from pages where they should have voted to close.
   - Freezing the rep changes isn't a punishment as much as it is a coersion to prompt the user to post their resolving advice on the dupe target (if it is in fact unique there). If they have something unique and valuable to add -- add it to the target page so that researchers can compare answers on one page instead of many pages.
   - Downvotes on answers would not generate rep loss while the page is closed, but it would allow curators to vote to delete negatively scored answers.
3. How to manage cultural change about signposts?

   - Clarify the goal explicitly in the Help pages. State the criteria and encourage contentious up/down voting.
   - Award "Nice/Good/Great Signpost" badges for signposts that acquire 10/25/100 upvotes AFTER being closed.
   - Add a thin banner just above an answer to a signpost (only presented to the poster of the answer and only while the page is closed) that informs them that upvotes will not generate rep points and that if they can add something unique and valuable to the signpost's target, they should post an answer there.

I realize this would be a shake up for a lot of users.  I am hoping to hear constructive answers to this question.  Keep in mind, this is not a feature request.

p.s. This question is related to, but not a duplicate of: [Make Stack Overflow more friendly: remove the stigma of duplicates?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366725/2943403)

Comment: *" When I see a new question that has been asked before, I race to hammer it closed, downvote it, and seek its urgent deletion."* I know I'm picking on a specific sentence here, but just want to put my perspective on that this sentence is true *if* the question is poor quality; many duplicates are (especially for questions that are asked often). There are certainly well asked duplicates; sometimes the Op as simply not searched the right keywords but show good effort and research. These you can still hammer as quickly as you want, but then you should **upvote** it

Comment: I agree, this will take new discipline/thinking though.  Gotta unlearn some behaviors.

Comment: I'd go much further than "disable rep gains/losses" - all gains/losses are *reversed* if the post is dupe-closed and not reopened for a certain period of time (to allow for incorrect closures to be processed).

Comment: I don't know if I like rep freezes or not on duplicate posts. Sometimes an answer on a duplicate can be more useful than the dupe target because it uses a method not on the dupe. moving the answer to the other question is likely wrong, as it wouldn't make sense on the other question. I do, however, strongly agree that disincentivising answering duplicate questions is something i would like to see; I get fed up of the amount of times certain questions get the same answer.

Comment: In truth, in regards to answers on dupes, I'd much rather see [so] fix the "problem" of *some* users being able to post answers (sometimes hours) after the question has been closed (as a duplicate); seeing people answer a frequent duplicate 10+ minutes after I have hammered it doesn't help the problem.

Comment: I removed the meta commentary directing users how to behave, especially WRT their votes. Not only was it incorrect (on Meta, users downvote discussion posts they disagree with), but telling users how to vote or what not to do is a sure-fire way to get downvoted into oblivion, which would run counter to your stated goal of engendering discussion.

Comment: "What is a good signpost?"  possibly worthy of it's own question

Comment: "When I see a new question that has been asked before..." if you recognize question has been asked before that is a pretty good sign such question is not a good sign post. Good sign posts ask different question.

Comment: I'm skeptical that it's possible to disincentivize answers, just like it's not possible to force gold badgers to use the hammer. Some people will just answer whatever they can, some people will just upvote posts that are technically correct, etc. We could consider undoing the rep change if the question gets hammered within a short time (24h? 36h?) but this is open for abuse as it gives one gold badge the power to take rep away from others with questionable closures (whereas deleting needs 3+ people to agree) and mods would have a hard time assessing abuse in minor tags.

Comment: One of the qualities of a good signpost is not having answers on it. I would like there to be an agreed policy and process for deleting answers on dupes even if they are correct, accepted and upvoted, if they do not provide anything beyond the answers on the dupe target. That removes some incentive for answering dupes; it makes dupes into better signposts; and it leaves the question for the roomba to decide whether it is worth keeping or not.

Comment: @khelwood I mostly agree.  Please consider consolidating your thoughts in this topic and posting an answer.  The only minor possible benefit in having explained answers under the signpost is that the answer may have "search critical" keywords in it that helps the signpost to be found.

Comment: me: you can't get rid of the stigma. What needs to disappear is the concept of the signpost, we're not evolved enough yet to be able to handle layers. Don't treat dupes any differently than any other question when it comes to judging how to quality vote and if and when to delete vote.

Comment: Just a reminder that if this [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions) is still considered current policy, then answers today should be upvoted/downvoted only on the merits of how good an answer they are, and not downvoted because they happened to have been posted before the question was marked a dup or closed for some other reason.  As many have likely observed, this is not always the way things are done today.  So, some of the discussion items in this post are counter to this philosophy (like revoking answer rep).

Comment: @khelwood - And who exactly is going to compare the answers on a dup to each of the answers on each of the possible dups and decide that one answer doesn't add anything new so it can be deleted?  That's a laborious process that requires a lot of judgement (quite subjective), requires holding a lot of info in your head at once and SO has no process at all for and no incentive for anyone to participate in that.   IMO, the whole notion that a targeted and good answer is a bad thing on a question that happens to ultimately get marked a dup is just wrong.  That answer does no harm.

Comment: @jfriend00 Subject Matter Experts (SMEs), the same people who identify dupes, try to curate the site, and would like the ability to do it better. It sounds like you think there is no incentive for finding dupes either; but people do it because they are trying to improve and support the site.  By all means, you curate the things you want to curate, and I likewise. Since I am not paid for it, my curation priorities are my own to decide.

Comment: @khelwood - The purpose of part of this discussion is whether to make a new policy about removing existing answers on dupped questions. That is the context of my comment to you.  No site policy will be successful unless there are people who are likely to carry it out and make it work. I was asking a question about that. And, I think we should consider how much work it is and how the priority of the work compares to other things people could be encouraged to spend their curation time on.  Your suggestion seems like a high work, low benefit activity which makes it undesirable to implement.

Comment: @jfriend00 Deletion is part of curation, and redundant duplication is one of the things appropriate for deletion. We have delete votes for such purposes. And they are used, whether you think it is the optimal use of people's time or not.

Comment: If an answer on a dupe closed page adds no new value to the insights provided on the dupe target, would it be fair to say that it is "not helpful"? These answers are then justifiably downvoted, even if correct, no? Curators do not exclusively downvote from the perspective of "is this resolving advice for the asker". We also vote on behalf of "future researchers" (by expecting educational/explained answers to be fit for general use), and "the system" (by identifying redundant content for the noise that is it).  If nothing is noise, then the signal is not well defined ...[cough] LinkedIn.

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine I don't know. I've never needed to use Wikipedia.  Is it still alive or is it in financial ruin?  All of the answers that I require in life are usually somewhere in the Stack Exchange universe. :)

Comment: 1. Sounds like you're reiterating [ask].

Comment: @Rounin Merger. See [WP:REDUNDANTFORK](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:REDUNDANTFORK)

Comment: Why do you want to disincentivize answering signposts? Sometimes, like Larnu said, answers on a duplicate will approach the problem differently, and might not apply to the original. That's not a bad thing.

Comment: 3. Which help pages are you referring to? I like the badge idea btw :)

Comment: @wjandrea because more times than not, the rushed answers come without the slightest search for a duplicate because they want to get their daily rep.  I resent that the system incentivizes answering pages that should be closed while not rewarding the people that actually help the system and the asker by closing duplicates.  If answering dupes is not bad, fine by me, let's not close pages that are duplicates; tell me that I can gobble up 250 every day by answering basic dupes. (Help Pages = https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: I mean, people do that every day with impunity. ‍♂️ so much for consequences

Comment: @mickmack *"the system incentivizes answering pages that should be closed while not rewarding the people that actually help the system and the asker by closing duplicates."* -- That's a great point. I have a pipe dream that closures could be up/downvoted, then you could have duplicate closures net, say 1 point per vote for the close-voters. (And it could also be used to show that the community agrees with the closure, but that's a separate topic.) *"answering basic dupes"* -- Well hold on, cause that's not what I'm saying; I'm saying answers that add **unique** content are useful.

Comment: @wjandrea Do you support downvoting the correct answers to duplicate questions when they aren't adding unique content?  Because most of the new answer that I see to dupe question are not bringing anything new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mickmack Oh, the help pages overall. I wasn't sure if you meant ones that specifically cover signposts -- namely https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates -- or all the ones that cover asking and answering, like [ask] and [answer] too.

Comment: @mickmack *"Do you support downvoting the correct answers to duplicate questions when they aren't adding unique content?"* -- No, because if it's the right answer, there's no reason to downvote. Sometimes I'll even upvote if it's an especially apt answer to the duplicate question and the answers on the original are more general/abstract. On the other hand, sometimes I'll leave a comment that's like "This is already covered in (this answer) and in more depth."

Comment: Everybody's talking about "signposts", but nobody seems to have defined what a "signpost" is.  Is it different from a canonical version of the question?  And if so, why should answering it be disincentivized?

Comment: @jamesdlin My definition of a good signpost is a duplicate page which serves as a traffic controller because of its unique [mcve] and has specific search terms in its text to help researchers locate it.  The job of a signpost is not to provide the solution to the problem but to refer researchers to the canonical question where the community's very best answers are stored, compared, and sorted for quality.  THIS improves the researcher experience because researchers don't need to hold different solutions in their head while bounce between tens of different pages on the same topic.

Answer (score 10):

First, I want to readdress this point as I think my answer to it is probably the most important point of this answer:

> When I see a new question that has been asked before, I race to hammer it closed, downvote it, and seek its urgent deletion.

Again, although I know that I am addressing a single sentence in solitude, this is one of the two main view points on duplicates. The other one being that it doesn't matter the question is a duplicate, answer it anyway. I'm not going to address the importance of closing/flagging questions as duplicates here, that's a different subject, but it *is* important and closing (hammering) the question as quickly as you want is still the correct action. What you should, however, be doing is considering the quality of the duplicate question. These probably fall into the following categories:

1. No attempt has been shown in the question, nor research effort. Question is more of a "Gief me da codez".
2. Question has (many) duplicate questions, including at least one canonical duplicate. An Attempt has been made, however, it is likely no research effort was made, as if there had been the OP would not be asking the question they are.
3. Question has been asked before, but it's not a prominent problem. OP has linked to a popular problem, but it actually have no relevance. No attempt given.
4. Question has been asked before, and a good attempt had been shown. OP has a also shown research, however, the problem was a lack of the right keyword/methodology.
5. Regardless of how often the problem has been asked, the OP shows a good attempt. They also link to several questions which are dupe candidates.

1 is by far, from my experience, the most common. These are the ones you should be closing, downvoting and deleting; they aren't going to be useful to anyone else but the OP and the answer is available elsewhere. For 2, again, hammer the question, as for downvoting, that is up to you; some are more strict on a lack of research than others, and things like how easy the search term is to find can weigh heavily (I, for example, have a dim view when you can put the title of the question into Google and get the canonical dupe). 3 falls in the same boat as this, in my opinion. For 4 and 5, however, these are questions that should be upvoted; these are good questions, no matter how common the problem. These will be able to act as signposts in the future.

Disincentivising answering duplicate questions is something I am in favour of, however, I can't say I agree with the suggestion(s) in your question. Questions are sometimes closed as duplicates long after they have been answered, and the answer given on the duplicate can use different methodology to that of the dupe; these can be **good** answers and stopping them earning reputation is "wrong". Saying that, for answers that are posting within minutes of the question, and the question is closed within minutes as well, I would not be against it then; that would stop people playing [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) with such questions.

In truth, as I mentioned in the comments, I would much rather Stack Overflow first fix the "problem" of answers being able to be added to questions after they are closed (sometimes hours after). Though there is certainly no evidence to suggest this opinion is true, it is in my experience that users that tend to post answers on duplicate answers are also those that avoid the closure validation when submitting their answer. The fact that the behaviour differs from user to user (and their browser settings) is a [different problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357558), but I feel is related.

I don't, however, have a proposed solution at this time for disincentivising the behaviour. Downvoting the answers is likely not the solution either; the whole idea is very similar to downvoting answers to bad questions and the person punished should really be the asker not the answerer (though the answerer is promoting bad question behaviour). The only real way I can see it being addressed properly is with the community ensuring that they close duplicates quickly; as we get more users with hammers that'll be easier. I can also see the Staging Ground helping there, as duplicates can be closed before an answer can even be posted. *Side thought, this makes me think that the SG should have an option to upvote a question once it leaves the SG even if you close it as a duplicate.*

As for how to change the culture, for bad questions, then do what you stated at the start; get those bad questions deleted. If users who are adamant they want to answer low quality duplicates want to continue to do so, then any reputation they do gain will be lost when it's deleted, and the OP of the question will be a little closer to a question ban. This just means we need more people who are using their down, close, and delete votes; there aren't enough of us and hopefully if we can get enough people to use them correctly, then maybe those that keep answering such questions will learn that they can't "win the game" when they lose their easily earned reputation when their content is deleted.

For good (duplicate) questions, then as I said above, close and **upvote** them; those questions won't be roomba'd then and future users will be able to be redirected when using the search terms of that question, and perhaps their even upvote both the original question as well the question/answers on the duplicate post.

Comment: When it comes to deleted questions, the Roomba is the *last* thing I worry about.  Upvoting them is still good but if Enough People™ decide that the question is still worthy of deletion, they can simply downvote it enough to then get it to a state where it can be deleted very simply.

Comment: Voting rings is a completely different problem, @Makoto .

Comment: I agree, but I'm also highlighting that they may be the bigger problem rather than the Roomba from 2014 that only holds like maybe an eighth's worth of the dust it did when you got it back then.

Comment: If the only thing you took from the above is Roomba, then you've missed the whole point of my post; roomba was one of the smallest parts.

Comment: "the OP shows a good attempt. They also link to several questions which are dupe candidates" ... and they also explain how those aren't duplicates (and this reasoning is valid). Sometimes users disagree that another question is a duplicate, but then they end up accepting an answer that's almost word-for-word the same as the top answer to that question (although this is usually if someone else links to it, not if they link to it themselves). Showing some research doesn't justify an upvote if that research is bad.

Comment: As far as I've seen, and of course I could be wrong, but people answering questions after they're closed is such a rare occurrence that it's really not a problem that worth bothering to fix. Especially not when that comes at the cost of preventing someone from posting an answer they're put hours of work into, to a question they thought was fine, and may in fact *be* fine, given the subjectivity of closure (and such prevention is frustrating, even if the alternative is just posting it temporarily until the closed question is deleted).

Comment: Can we have an extra big disincentive for people who both answer the question AND vote to close it?

Answer (score 9):

So congratulations, you've arrived at [the conclusion I did back in 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309320/1079354), which was [reaffirmed by myself in 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361373/1079354).  I've got a lot of history in this area so you can [go spelunking through my post history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1079354+deletion) to know how I really feel about this subject matter.

To be perfectly honest, I don't think we're ever going to see a consensus on what is a "good" signpost.  Realistically speaking we could talk about bad ones until the cows come home, but something that's objectively good is a lot harder to enumerate simply because they're *very* seldom upvoted.

Larnu's suggestion on upvoting duplicates you find that would make for good signposts is a healthy approach since it means that it's less likely to get deleted out-of-hand, and provides useful (weak) signal to others looking for a solution to their question.

What I would espouse instead is a sentiment of establishing clear conventions and definitions on when deletion of any post is acceptable.  [I've been shot down on this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407889/1079354) but it bears repeating - if the privilege is being misused, we should start clamping down on the use of the privilege.

Comment: Yeah, hard to get a consensus on what a "good" signpost means as it involves judgement calls on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: The real problem is that judging what a good signpost is requires predicting the future. Often, what we think is not a good sign post will turn out, if left alone, to be extremely useful. It's the same dark art as SEO, fortune-telling, and crystal-ball construction. The same quality standards should be applied as any other post: if it's incoherent or otherwise problematic, delete it. Otherwise, keep it as a signpost. We aren't supposed to be trying to judge sign posts based on their quality.

Comment: Let's keep an open mind about what the future of Stack Overflow can look like.  While it is a fact that there isn't yet a definition for a "good signpost", this doesn't prevent us from daring to forge one.  I'll also grant you that we are highly unlikely to craft a perfect definition, but perfect can be the enemy of good in this case.  Like the Trending Sort algorithm, let's make a solemn attempt to make things better and commit to continued honing of the definition over time. @CodyGray

Comment: The thing is, @mick, if we guess wrong and delete everything that doesn't meet our forged definition, we'll have created an unfalsifiable situation: our guess cannot ever be proven wrong, because we'll have deleted everything that we didn't think was a good signpost. I fundamentally don't see where the issue is. There is no *need* to delete questions once they've been marked as a duplicate. The database has no problem holding them.

Comment: "I don't think we're ever going to see a consensus on what is a "good" signpost" I disagree. A good signpost has to be a good question first. The second requirement is that it should add useful keywords, but that's something I would do after the fact (when I try to see our [current list of cannon questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%2b%2b?tab=Frequent) and see that there are more than 10 duplicates). Of course, if it's something egregious, like posting the title of the question and finding the duplicate, vote to delete is not unreasonable.

Comment: @Braiam:  Going to disagree with the first sentiment.  A bad question (or a badly worded question) can make an excellent sign post if the "right" way to phrase a question is still not popular or common, or if the easier way to express the problem is still what Google/Bing/DuckDuckGo auto-complete.

Comment: But the point that Cody is making, @Braiam, is that there's no risk of us running out of disk storage if we *don't* delete these duplicates.  I want to see a really convincing argument that proves, beyond a shadow of a doubt, that these duplicates are so horribly toxic and caustic that they *must* be removed from the site.  Otherwise...why bother?  It's not meant to be a super downvote.

Comment: Well, that's not the only thing being cluttered. Search results are also cluttered, which I presume was why google decided to [list all the post in a compact way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd1nv.png), which not many search engine has chosen to (sometimes I have to scroll two pages on DDG). The storage space isn't the _only_ space. The search space is probably more important, since that's what future readers are more interested of (cc @cody ) (Lets ignore for a hot minute that nothing is ever deleted on SE, just soft-deleted)

Comment: "A bad question (or a badly worded question)" I don't conflate both, in fact I make exception for the badly (I would call it differently) worded one as long as it "add useful keywords". A bad question is one that doesn't achieve even that. There's a limited number of words in language to describe the same thing, 10 variations is a good ballpark to probably say that it's enough.

Answer (score 7):

I would rather see some effort spent at where those sign posts point at. A lot of our current, supposedly canonical duplicates are of mediocre quality, yet hopelessly up-voted. Meaning that they can never be improved because:

- Newer higher quality answers posted at the canonical question will get shadowed by the old, up-voted worse ones.

  One perfect example: [Which functions from the standard library must (should) be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565727/which-functions-from-the-standard-library-must-should-be-avoided) The accepted, up-voted answer is partially incorrect and spreading dangerous misinformation (using `strncpy` as a safe version of `strcpy`). 5 years ago I tried to post a high quality answer to counter it, complete with actual sources for my claims. Several others have tried as well. Still the post with dangerous misinformation sits at +60 score and remains accepted. It's a lost cause.

  Another perfect example: [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior) This is the target to the *by far* most frequently asked C and C++ question, so the canonical dupe is ridiculously up-voted accordingly. But the accepted answer with +600 score just says "it's undefined behavior" without further explanation or good sources, just some Wikipedia articles. A much better answer was posted by haccks 7 years ago, but it sits at a relatively modest +86 votes, doomed to live in the shadow of the accepted answer.
- Newer higher quality *questions* with high quality answers will not become the new canonical duplicate, because some trigger-happy close voter will swiftly close them down. Instead of closing the old, worse post which has "canonical" status currently.

Conclusion: the up/down voting system and the duplicate vote systems of SO are not suitable for picking out actual high-quality content. Instead the "bandwagon" mentality of the Internet can give posts canonical status at a whim.

Sign posts do not help solving this problem. They are in fact part of the problem, enforcing the bandwagon mentality. Now some of those closed-as-duplicate posts might actually be of higher quality than the dupe target. Or they could have been, if they weren't closed too early.

I don't think there are any easy solutions to these voting problems, it is status-by-bad-design. But at the very least we could spend our effort and votes on the actual canonical dupe targets instead, striving to improve those as much as we can.

Comment: new "trending" sort option experiment might be of help here - it already shows signs of shooting new answers gathering upvotes to the top, outpacing the older answers with thousands of votes. With the recent unpinning of accepted answers from the top, we might see a lot of improvement here.

Comment: What would be nice s having a way to "reverse the polarity" of duplicates - I often see "target" being misinterpreted as "the oldest question asked" instead of "the best Q&A from the two".

Comment: @Lundin I do not disagree with your (negative/unsavory) observations. I've seen many mis-sorted pages (even with the trending sort applied). Awareness is the first step to solving a problem.  So it seems we need to simultaneous change the 
"bandwagon" culture on old canonicals.  Perhaps we need to be open to the idea of giving birth to new canonicals where old canonicals are harming the researcher experience.  But how?

Comment: I have spoken in SOCVR about wanting to have a committee of silver/gold badgers to vote (democratically) about which page(s) should be deemed the canonical for a topic/technique/error.  However, doing this properly means scraping together ALL pages on a topic/technique/error so that evaluators can compare the aggregate fairly.  The voting could not only nominate canonicals, but also nominate dupes that are not worth keeping as signposts.  This would prevent overzealous gold badgers from funnelling all dupes to their own answer and unnecessarily deleting good signposts and maybe reopening.

Comment: For what it’s worth, my [weighed Wilson score script](https://stackapps.com/q/8912/77981) sorts haccks’s answer first under the latter question, and an answer advising against `strn*` functions under the former.

Comment: Other than weighed Wilson scoring, I think two other interventions may help: always display separate upvote and downvote counts for answers (not just an aggregate score); and increase the reputation penalty for receiving a downvote on an answer; maybe even make it higher than the amount you received for a single answer upvote. The first may help readers identify potentially misleading answers (the same way people used to take advantage of dislike counts on YouTube); the latter will disincentivise writing misleading answers in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

I have no stigma toward signposts, and I don't think it's necessary to rush to delete duplicates.

In fact, I don't even think duplicates should be deleted at all before a user with the 10.000 reputation privilege could — i.e. before 2 days since closure and with a score of -3 or lower. If the post is so abysmal that it warrants immediate deletion it probably should've been closed with some other reason than duplicate.

Leaving the closed duplicate up for a couple days gives the OP the opportunity to review the duplicate targets and possibly edit their question to show why those don't answer their question. This is perhaps a rare occurrence, but nevertheless something we should allow the time for.

With that said, I'm definitely in favor of deleting bad signposts, after some time has passed. However I don't think there is a conclusive answer to:

> What is a good signpost?

**Duplicates need to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis**. There's simply too many variables at play.

I'm afraid that trying to formalize this definition is a moot exercise. I usually employ to main criteria to assess the quality of a duplicate:

- does it offer unique search keywords? A good signpost drives traffic
- does it **save** people's time? A good signpost takes you to the solution faster

About keywords, it's hard to predict accurately how successful they will be. Moreover, the people who hammer questions are the same experts who would not look something up with the wrong keywords. Other variables that play a role are frequency of the duplicate, number of views, quality of existing answers, popularity of the tag, etc. There aren't easy heuristics here.

About saving people's time, you have to individually assess the existing answers (if any) and see if they provide valuable advice, conflict with answers in the dupe target, if there's lengthy comment threads that may hijack the conversation or hide the real solution, etc. Again, no easy heuristics.

> How can answering signposts be disincentivized?

It can't be disincentivized. Some users just answer whatever they can, and for whatever reason. We don't really know what motivation they have for contributing to the site. Some may do it for the reputation points, some because they genuinely enjoy helping others. If you take rep out of the equation, you may reduce motivation for the first group of users but not for the second.

As long as answers on a duplicate aren't technically wrong or actively harmful, there's no reason to hate them. In particular **there's no reason to downvote just because they exist under the duplicate**.

You may think that an answer under a duplicate is unhelpful by definition, and thus meets the condition for downvoting, but frankly that's a bit of a stretch. I might downvote answers only when they are actually wrong or don't answer the question. Otherwise, just let them be.

> How to manage cultural change about signposts?

Honestly I think there's no pressing need for a cultural change. Just hammer duplicates and upvote good ones.

If you think a certain duplicate doesn't offer long-lasting value to the site — being the umpteenth one may be a factor in this, go ahead and vote to delete; but don't rush.

Except for obvious garbage, give each post *a little bit of time* to prove themselves.

Comment: Yes, duplicates are not a problem as long as there are pointers towards to the canonical questions. Search engines, for some reason, prefer the low-scored duplicates with low-quality answers (often one or two "try this" answers). It is a real problem if the canonical questions are not *easily* found (very low efficiency in using Stack Overflow for its most common use case by far).

Comment: It is this very "the system can't be fix, don't even try" philosophy that makes me want to do a 180, stop hammering, and just answer every dupe.  I am confident that I can post more informative, more generous answers than the FGITW answers that get sprayed onto new questions.  What if all curators would revolt because the system is not well designed to protect itself?  Would that be enough of a catalyst for change?  If answers on duplicates aren't bad, then why the hell do we bother preventing answers from being posted after a page is closed as a dupe???  Let's load it up with dupe answers!

Comment: I am so fed up with devoting so much of my time trying to help this place in vain.  If asking a dupe isn't inherently bad and answering a dupe isn't inherently bad, then closing dupes is certainly bad because it is preventing non-bad things from happening.

Comment: @mickmackusa I understand where your frustration comes from. I invite you to consider a couple things: 1) not-bad doesn't imply good; 2) the "battle" against dupe-answerers simply can't be won. Even if SE fixes being able to submit answers after the post is closed, there'll always be someone who can jot down an answer faster than you can find a target. You have to come to terms with that, if for anything, do it for your own sanity. Don't burn out trying to slam shut ASAP poor questions. Just hammer dupes, and vote to delete them when they are unlikely to offer lasting value.

Comment: Also, perhaps the Staging Ground will provide an additional avenue to moderate content before it becomes publicly visible, thus reducing the opportunity for dupe-answerers to thwart curation efforts.

Answer (score 4):

One of the qualities of a good signpost is not having answers on it. Answers on a dupe only interrupt visitors who should be getting guided to the dupe target.

I would like there to be an agreed policy and process for deleting answers on dupes even if they are correct, accepted and upvoted, if they do not provide anything beyond the answers on the dupe target. That removes some incentive for answering dupes; it makes dupes into better signposts; and it leaves the question for the roomba to decide whether it is worth keeping or not.

(Answers that *do* provide something new are presumably good candidates for being moved over to the dupe target, consolidating all the useful information in one place.)

Comment: Also the [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) page says "If the question closed as a duplicate has no answers, then anonymous users will be automatically redirected to the question it is marked as a duplicate of", so in the absence of answers the "signposting" is automatic and transparent to many visitors.

Comment: The most appropriate way to do this would be to have moderators periodically merge answers from the duplicate question into the main question. The reason we *don't* do this is because the questions are rarely *exact* duplicates. More sensible duplicate-closing rules/behavior should help facilitate dealing with duplicate answers, too.

Comment: @CodyGray good thing [I proposed to change the system to make guidance more sensible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378147/213575)

Answer (score -7):

I think there's a point of view missing here in the discussion so far - too often marking something as a duplicate simply isn't enough help for the OP to actually solve their problem. It's a duplicate in concept, but not in code execution and thus is not sufficient help for the OP to figure out how to solve their actual coding problem.  It's akin to telling them to go read pages in the textbook.

As is pointed out in the original post here, the whole point of signposts is to build a path (likely via search) to one canonical answer on a topic which is all part of the long term reference value of stackoverflow.  No argument there.

But, the other side of the equation is that the engine that drives stackoverflow is when new users come here and ask questions, they get treated well, they get good, on-target answers that answer their specific question and then afterwards, they both ask more questions and participate in the community, helping build its value in multiple ways (asking questions, answering questions, voting and helping curate).

So, I would argue, the site achieves the most success when there is an **appropriate balance** between policies that help make new users successful upon visiting the site and policies that lead to SO being a valuable online reference for future users.  In designing policies to help the site be a valuable online reference, we still have to keep site of how that impacts new users coming to the site and make sure we have the right balance.

To accomplish the first part of making new users successful, we need to encourage new users to come, we need to help new users get good answers to their specific questions, we need to see that new users get effectively coached on how to write good questions and how to best participate in the site (upvoting, accepting, searching before posting, etc...).

Hopefully, none of that is controversial so far.

Where some contention starts to occur is when deciding whether slamma jamma close dup (or as the OP stated "hammer it closed, downvote it, and seek its urgent deletion") is actually the right choice or not.  As we all know, a good question posts a specific coding problem.  I have this code, I want it to do X, but it's not doing that or it's doing Y instead.  I read about Z, tried it like this but couldn't get it to work.

The ideal answer (from the point of view of the user asking the question) is an answer that explains the concepts that the person asking the question is not understanding and then shows them specifically and precisely how those concepts can be applied in their code to fix it.  This gives the user seeking help, a specific fix for their code and a specific explanation targeted at exactly what they got wrong or didn't understand.

In the Javascript world, a classic example (which comes up multiple times a day) is a relatively new Javascript programmer encountering some problem with asynchronous operations and not understanding how to properly code that.  There are a couple canonical answers on that topic that are widely referenced and often used as duplicate targets (I mark dups of them myself from time to time).  And, from only the standpoint of signposts for long term search, this probably works for SO.

But, the canonical answers rarely address the OP's specific code.  They were written for someone else's code example and, if they became canonical, they presumably have some sort of good textbook-like description of the general type of problem (e.g. they're good answers that explain things).  But, asynchronous problems in general are not all solved the same way.  How you approach a solution depends a lot on what APIs you have, whether you're just making one asynchronous call or have several you want to sequence, whether you have interfaces that support promises or not, etc...  There are thousands of different sub-problems that all stem from the same asynchronous concepts that need more targeted solutions or discussion.

So, the classic case is that we have a relatively inexperienced coder, posting a well-formed question that includes their specific code and describes the specific problem they had with it. The general concept they got wrong or are not understanding properly is described in another answer.  But that other answer doesn't offer them a coding solution to their specific problem.

We can slam it closed as a dup, downvote them and punish people who provided a specific answer to them that shows them how to fix their specific code issue. That leaves the person asking the question kind of wondering what happened.  They wrote a well-formed question, they  got downvoted, their question got closed.  They got a link to some reference material that is related conceptually, but doesn't show them how to fix their specific code.

Essentially, we told them: **shame on you for asking, go read the textbook**.  I say "textbook" here because in most cases, a duplicate is a duplicate in concept only, not in specific code.  So, for the OP to make use of the duplicate, they have to study it like they would a textbook, learn what it says, then figure out how to apply that to their specific code.  Oftentimes, that leap from the concept to their code is EXACTLY what the OP is struggling with.  They don't know how to apply that concept to their code and the duplicate isn't getting them all the way to a solution.  They may have even done their own online research and seen the concepts mentioned in the duplicate and not understood how to apply that to their situation.

If you were working in the study hall in high school and a student comes in and they are stuck on a particular math homework problem and want some help.  Do you just point them to the appropriate page in the textbook and tell them to read that and refuse to help any further?  No, you don't only do that.  You provide whatever material is needed to help them understand the relevant concepts and then you help them to apply that to the specific problem they are working on.  You want to follow the concept through to applying it to their specific problem.

Unfortunately, far too many times when we mark question as a duplicate, we're really just telling them to "go read the textbook" and we're sending a very mixed message to the person asking the question. I'm sure there are many examples where posters see the dup reference and they "get it" and see how to apply that to their situation.  No problem there.  But, in many other cases, the poster is going to just feel like they got fed a link to a question that has 40 answers and is 20 pages long and isn't sufficient for them to figure out how to fix their code.  This user didn't really have a very good experience here.  They got negative feedback for posting.  They didn't get a solution to their problem.

From the standpoint of the new user with the kind of question that just pointing them to a dup on the same concept won't actually be sufficient for them to solve their specific coding issue, the best outcome would actually be to get BOTH a few references to good answers on the same concept AND a specific explanation and coding solution for their specific problem.  And, that might even be better for the site in the long run because the question/answer serves as both a signpost to the "canonical" answer on the topic and a specific solution to this actual coded question, either of which may be useful to future readers.

So, I guess this is a long-winded way of saying that if we're going to achieve a balance between helping new users get specific solutions to their actual problems and curate the site for long term reference, we can't just be looking for the fastest way to close something as a conceptual dup and penalize anyone trying to help the OP with a specific solution to their specific coding issue.

Comment: There is a flawed assumption in your "study hall" thought experiment - if we were paid (or unpaid) professors then sure, we would sit down and guide users through every misunderstanding / lack of knowledge they mght have. Such is the goal of an *educational* institution - to *educate*. Our goal is not so - it is, and has always been: to build a repository of high-quality questions and answers to every programming problem there is. If a user struggles with applying basic concepts, that's, frankly, their own problem - feel free to engage in a comment or chat discussion, but that's not the goal.

Comment: I disagree with Oleg.  I feel as an answerer and as a closer, that my duty it to deliver my recommended insights with the intent to educate and empower the asker and thousands of researchers.  I hold myself to a very hight standard and this is why I never win the FGITW game.  I also search for dupes BEFORE answering.  This results in slow answering from me.  More commonly, other answerers do not check for dupes, they fire a correct answer and enjoy upvotes while I am hunting for the best, most informative dupe.  So what happens, I do the curation and don't get a reward, while others do.

Comment: As for the new user experience.  Yes, we do have canonicals that basically say "go do some research then ask a better question".  These are often used when the asker shows zero effort -- I actually have no problem with this.  If they aren't going to try hard to self-solve then why should the burden be put on our volunteers.  If they don't like the canonical they are given, we expect them to edit their question to show how they tried to implement the referenced advice.  They could have skipped this annoyance by including their research and effort when they first posted.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think we don't actually disagree on that :) My point above (admittedly not as clear as it should have been) does not preclude answerers from providing as much detail as possible - just that the *focus* should be exactly on helping countless other users by making the solution generic enough, not specifically tailored and regurgitated so it can only ever apply to the OP's situation. The above does not argue that helping the author is not part of the deal, just that it is a side-effect (on which I hope we do agree).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - Well, you hit the nail right on the head for why I posted.  **So, SO has no goal to educate novice coders who struggle to apply basic concepts?**  Wow, I didn't know that.  I thought it's purpose was to help people and, while doing so, also build a valuable repository.  This would explain why I'm regularly frustrated at attempts at curation that interfere with actually helping people.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - FYI, the study hall at our high school is staffed by student volunteers, not paid teachers, just like SO.

Comment: @jfriend00 that has always been the goal, I am [quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming". That is the goal, not acting as a free *help desk*. It does not preclude anyone from helping users *in the process*, but that is not the goal, no, it's just that - a side-effect.

Comment: @jfriend00 that is also why I mentioned "unpaid" in brackets - it does not matter. In neither case are we an educational institution, and any such analogy misses the point. A book *educates* the reader just as much, but it is a side-effect of it - its primary goal is to contain, preserve, and pass knowledge. Such is the goal of a collection of items of knowledge (aka, a library) - which we *are*.

Comment: Here's the part that I find myself struggling with in recent times:  Signposts are supposed to be good, but we don't know what will be a good signpost (in real time).  We are not meant to answer and hammer duplicates because it is considered an abuse of our privilege.  I prefer not to answer dupes because I get irritated by users that knowingly answer dupes for the sake of rep points.  So by curating/hammering, I effectively seal myself out of being able to contribute to the collection of good signposts.  It all just seems conflicting and unfair to me as a contributor.

Comment: @mickmackusa I wonder if answer + hammer would be better received if an answer of the one hammering was to be auto-converted to a community wiki (not an ideal solution, but still). It seems that the negative sentiment regarding hammer+answer almost exclusively revolves around rep points.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - Your sentiment should lead to immediately closing and deleting questions that will never be useful long term references and should provide guidance for new posts that they MUST be the kind of post that will be a good long term reference.  Shouldn't there be a specific close reason "Not a useful long term reference question"?

Comment: @jfriend00 no, not at all. I do not act like I have clairvoyance on whether something is going to have lasting value in some unspecified future (and wish more users did not either). If standard close reasons apply, the question should be closed, otherwise - not. On a related note, if you recall, such a reason actually *existed* and was called "too localized", replaced by "no repro or typo". While I am a fan of the former wording more than the *current* one, I'd prefer a stricter definition that does not involve leaf-reading.

Comment: So far, I'm getting the sense that site curation is the ONLY goal.  There is no explicit goal to actually help anyone.  And, there's no recognition that helping people is the underlying engine that actually drives getting new content.

Comment: We want quality questions, not complex ones, @jfriend00. Please, don't misunderstand that as a bias against newbies. Provided they ask a unique, clear, focused, not opinionated, on-topic and non-answered (oh, look, standard close reasons are all here), they are more than welcome to do so. But yes, contributing to a repository of knowledge comes with some expectations.

Comment: The goal should be that such "newbies" can find the help they need, *without needing to ask at all.* That goal scales far better than somehow hoping to provide the individualized tutoring they may need on a 1:1 basis in this environment. If that means closing things as duplicates so that more users end up on the best Q&A pair, so be it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - But, what was proposed in the OP here is to actually penalize people who provided an answer to a question that ultimately got marked a dup.  So, the answer has already happened.  The question is what to do with it.  I'm like you.  I think it's actually best when you have both a targeted, specific coding answer to the question that was asked AND a link to the "textbook" answer that has a lot more info on the concept.  And, I don't think that hurts the value of the long term repository either as you still have the signpost AND you have a specific coding answer..

Comment: So, is SO fine with this scenario: User posts question, gets marked dup, user can't apply info in dup to solve their specific problem.  User leaves SO frustrated and with negative sentiment about SO.  Is that the desired outcome once the question has been posted?

Comment: If they decide not to take the steps required to get their post reopened, yes.

Comment: Given that we get over 5000 qusstions a day these days, yes, this is an acceptable outcome,  @jfriend00. We cannot help everyone. The "good samaritan" approach does not scale.

Comment: I guess my motivation for 10 years and 13k+ answers was misguided.  I thought the goal was to help people and I was regularly frustrated when things got in the way of actually helping someone.  It's a weird sort of place to be where users seem to really appreciate what I do (630k rep), but I regularly disagree with people here on Meta.  A "go read the textbook" dup hammer isn't my idea of helping someone and the sentiment here is actively interested in preventing me from helping them and explicitly saying it's wrong for me to help them.  Time to re-evaluate my participation in SO.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - The proposal is to disincentive (e.g. punish) people who already tried to help.  That has nothing at all to do with operating at scale.  Far too often that's used as the justification for policies that it has nothing at all to do with.

Comment: I wasn't discussing this proposal, @jfriend00 - just your answer and assumptions about the goal of Stack Overflow.

Comment: "So, the answer has already happened. The question is what to do with it." Indeed. I've seen very good answers on duplicates, and would hate to see them penalised. I've also seen answers that are almost direct copies of what is on the duplicate already, and it's frustrating me to the point that I've almost completely stopped answering now. I do not know what to do with *both at once*. Personally, I would lean towards educating people how to properly handle duplicates, but it's not clearcut.

Comment: If the target doesn't have an answer that caters to the knowledge level of the new question, give it one. If the asker can't take, for example, `$("#foobar")` and adapt it to their own code `$("#actual-id")` I'm afraid they need more assistance than this platform was built to provide.

Comment: @kevinb - `$("#foobar")` is a ridiculous oversimplification of the problem being discussed.  Not helpful in any way.  And a solution to a much more complicated question using the op's own code would look completely out of place as an answer to a different question.  Probably even get down voted because it wouldn't belong there.

Comment: Yes, however, i'd argue the problem they're having in adapting the solution to their situation is a different question entirely. Coding is *full* of layered problems that need to be further broke down into their individual pieces. Take common async problems. The most common one people seem to believe they can just return from anywhere and have it populate their variable. That's not *just* an async/await problem, that's a vast misunderstanding of the language as a whole. Simply saying "use async/await, here's your code working" misses the point. That user needs more help than a Q&A gives.

Comment: @KevinB - I didn't advocate for an answer that only provided working code.  A good answer explains the asynchronous problem as it applies to their code, explains the specific concept they are missing and then shows them how you apply that concept to fix their problem.  It's never as simple as just adding `await`.  In fact, most of the async problems are still using plain callback interfaces and you either need to advise how to use the proper interface or shown them how to promisify it and then using promise control flow.  Yes, it's a layered problem, but one that can be taught in an answer.

Comment: in an answer... for one user... one a time... "teaching" each user the one bit they're missing, doomed to never actually help anyone other than said user,

Comment: If a new programmer (or... anyone else, since the human behind the account matters not for the purposes of Q&A) does not understand how to apply the information with which they've been provided, then they can and should *ask a **specific** question* about that. If they ask a general question, then are rightly pointed to the existing question(s) which already cover that ground. As has been noted, this is not a help desk. It is not our goal or interest to spoon-feed individual users. Questions are only valuable insofar as they contribute to our accumulated knowledge base.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - One challenge around dups is that the related SO incentives don't really point all in one direction.  There's no credit for marking a good dup.  There's no penalty for marking an inappropriate dup.  It's very hard for the OP to get their question reopened in any timely manner, no matter what they change. Yes, it happens, but not very often. It's maddening if you supply a good answer because you weren't aware of a dup that matched well enough to answer this specific problem, it gets marked a dup (maybe even an inappropriate dup) and then your answer get downvoted multiple times.

Comment: @KevinB - A good answer teaches the general concept in the framework of the specific problem the OP cares about.  I'd argue these answers are MORE valuable than many of the canonical answers that are really just like a textbook.  And, we're back to the general opinion that helping a user is of no value at all on Stackoverflow.  I'm getting that loud and clear from multiple directions.  You seem to have an assumption that I write answers that are never useful to other people while helping someone with their specific problem.  That isn't how I try to do things.

Comment: @CodyGray - I guess we could mark questions a dup of anything that is generally related and then add a comment to the effect: "If that duplicate reference doesn't help you solve your specific problem, then post a new question about exactly where you got stuck in applying that and be sure to reference that you've already read that specific set of answers (like them) and got stuck trying to apply it". But, nobody actually leaves that comment-they mark as a dup and sometimes the user is left with a bad experience and no understanding of how to fix their problem. But, I guess that isn't a concern.

Comment: Nobody should ever leave that comment, because the duplicate banner already says that. Now, of course, you are otherwise setting me up to refute a straw man. I never claimed that we should mark questions as a dupe of something generally related, or that we should mark questions as dupes without actually reading the question and determining whether it is already specific enough to not be a dupe.

Comment: @CodyGray - Please show me an example of where all the info in that comment is shown in the duplicate banner.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wonder if there is a difference between what the author of the question sees in the banner and what everyone else sees. I only see "this question already has answers here:" when I go to a question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: well, we know they do see something different, since we know the user is (incorrectly) advised to ask another question, not to edit it.

Comment: @Gimby - Yes, presumably there is a difference and since I don't have any of my own questions that were marked a dup (at least that I can find), I can't see what they see. I rather doubt the banner advises even close to everything in my comment which is why I asked to see what it does say.

Comment: [This is what an author sees in the duplicate question notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1FVk.png). The link "ask a new one" links to [the page to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @VLAZ - Thx.  In my suggested comment, I was trying to help the OP more specifically understand what to do if they weren't able to solve their problem after reading the dup - either because the dup was not specific enough for their problem or because they ran into problems in applying it to their code.

Comment: @jfriend00 There's a real simple rule of thumb. If there's a lot of views and upvotes on a Q&A, it's good. For whatever scenario you're thinking of, if it involves only the OP ever viewing and upvoting the answer, it's not good. Consider this a resource constrained solution to maximizing help, and we're setting up a culture where everyone does this.

Comment: @PasserBy - Yes, I've gotten the message loud and clear from Meta here.  Priority goes on unique and popular questions that are widely useful to the repository as a whole.  Any effort to help an individual get an answer to their specific nuanced question and solve their specific problem or make sure they have a good experience on SO is not valued and not prioritized over working on unique, popular questions.  Message received.  And, the thousands of users who have a bad experience on SO is of no consequence - just necessary collateral damage in the pursuit of the more valuable repository.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think you are overreacting a little. Various discussions so far tried to highlight that targeted help is not a *priority* but is still *welcome*. The only issue is that such help should not stand in the way of building a quality repository of knowledge.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - No, there's no overreacting here at all.  Every time I try to prioritize actually helping someone get a solution to their nuanced problem instead of slamming it closed as a dup or as needs details, that is shot down in favor of the process that prioritizes the repository as a whole.  That IS the message that is sent here on Meta.  That message is received loud and clear.  When I try to stand up here on Meta for throwing a little priority towards making sure the OP actually gets an answer or has a good experience, I am downvoted or encouraged not to.

Comment: @jfriend00 I said none of the latter. If you address the "resource constrained" part, there'd be a discussion to be had. Otherwise, this is going nowhere.

Comment: @PasserBy - I am my own resource.  I don't speak for or control any other resources.  The message I have received here from you and others on Meta is that you do not want me to spend my resource time on making sure an individual gets an answer to their nuanced question or has a good experience on SO unless it looks like it's a completely unique and likely popular question.

Comment: @jfriend00: Personally speaking I don't really *care* how you elect to spend your time on Stack Overflow.  I think that everyone else's argument is more centered around scalability.  You're just one individual.  Someone needing the kind of catered help you want to deliver pops onto the website about a thousand times an hour.  We *all* don't share this intrinsic goal that you have of wanting to help each and every person, because we're simply outnumbered.

Comment: @Makoto - Yes, it's very clear from the people who have chosen to participate in this conversation that there is no goal at all to make sure people get answers to their questions or have a good experience on stackoverflow.  The needs of the long term value of the repository trump EVERYTHING else.  So, EVEN when I choose to engage with someone to help them (either to help them clarify the question or to offer more detailed solution), I am regularly overridden and prevented when other people come along and slam the question closed, preventing me from helping them.  Message received.

Comment: I would prefer a solution that caters to both of us, to be honest. My hope is that the SG will provide.

Comment: And, yes it's also very clear from the tone here that there is little intrinsic interest among this group of people in actually helping people.  If you don't post a question that would be of great interest to the repository (even if it's completely on-topic), then lots of people here aren't really interested in helping.  I personally think that inevitably leads to a decline in stackoverflow's success because it is people asking questions that are ultimately the driver of success here, but there is no priority on them actually having a successful experience here.

Comment: No need to take it to that extreme, @jfriend00.  I'd say, treat it like a ten year old computer; you can do whatever you want with it but don't act so surprised when the company that made it tells you that they don't support it anymore.  Alternatively...you should spin up a whole separate discussion about this and figure out why people's visions don't align.  It'd be good to get an understanding or comprehension of this, honestly.

Comment: But maybe the heart of it is that you believe that we're here to teach, @jfriend00.  I believe that people can learn from us, [but that we're not here to explicitly teach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368938/1079354).  These two views are diametrically opposed, and that is why you are running into friction.  Again, you may do as you wish, but in the face of a difference in philosophy, don't be surprised with the amount of friction you get.

Comment: @KevinB - My understanding is that the SG is really only for first time asker questions (or perhaps low rep askers) to help them be more on-topic or have more clarity.   That's only one part of what I'm discussing.

Comment: @Makoto - Look at any of the popular canonical answers that lots of things marked dup of.  Are they not entirely trying to "teach"?  I don't get your resistance to the word teaching at all!  Writing a good answer does teach.  That's what a good answer does.  We don't just drop a coding solution with no explanation.   A good answer teaches both what the OP did wrong and why this is the right way to solve the problem. It teaches.  Show me a description of a really good answer that doesn't do any teaching! You've got me thoroughly confused.  I don't know how to right an answer that doesn't teach.

Comment: @Makoto - Actually, the only reason I'm posting here is because I'm not allowed to do as I want in helping people.  I'm regularly engaged with helping someone and the question gets closed with a resolution that doesn't actually help the OP.  I'm actively PREVENTED from helping people by the very sentiment in this discussion.

Comment: As one of the commenters who tried to explain to you that expecting SO to be *focused* on helping as opposed to being focused on curation is a misconception, @jfriend00, I feel personally offended by your comment about "group of people" with "little intrinsic interest ... in helping people". My activity (as well as such of many others who responded to you) on main (including answering, editing, reviewing, and flagging) is good example of a wrong assumption that being mindful about the end goal of SO to be a repository of knowledge precludes helping users in your sense of the term.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - All I've asked for here in my answer on this topic is a **balance** of consideration so that actually helping people get answers to their question gets some consideration and priority vs. curation - so there's a balance of interests.  So, that both objectives are considered relevant and important and that curation (particularly slamming questions closed without any interaction with the OP or even worse slamming them closed when someone else is already engaged with trying to help) isn't the only priority.

Comment: If you don't think we're striking that balance, it's better to start up a separate Meta discussion outlining where it is you believe we're failing.  Having this discussion in comments isn't going to make it visible enough for people to weigh in.

Comment: @Makato - I think it's fairly pointless.  I posted an answer here about prioritizing **balance** in the context of the signpost dups discussion.  Based on the feedback on my answer (which these are comments to) and the tone in the vast majority of the comments, it's pretty clear what the vocal people on Meta think.  Not sure there would be any value in rehashing that again as I just end up feeling like it's 4 or 5 of you against me every time I try to stand up for helping people actually get answers.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - FYI, in case you missed it, I was reacting to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417601/change-the-stigma-regarding-signposts/417631?noredirect=1#comment906934_417631) which contains *We all don't share this intrinsic goal that you have of wanting to help each and every person*.  Now, I never said I wanted to help every person.  I vote to close questions too. I skip over questions that aren't something I can productively engage on. But, when I am engaged in helping someone, it is quite a bummer to see site curation prevent me from helping.

Comment: @jfriend00 yup, I think I missed it, too much to keep track of, thanks. That said, the point about the "group of people" still stands. However, that does not mean we think you *act* in ways detriment to the site's goal, not at all. I know you answer, edit, review, VTC, and VTR a lot on main. The only point of contention here is the sentiment that curation emphasis should be reduced in favor of helping as many individual users *if possible*. The site's old and grew waaay out of the scope viable with focus on the latter - hence the perceived shift towards curation only.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - Well, my post here asking for some consideration of a **balance** between actually helping users vs. just building more signpost dup pointers is currently at -12 and +6 so a clear majority here on meta don't appear to want such a **balance**.  I raised an example of where a question could be targeted at a canonical dup, but the specifics of the OP's code are unlikely to be directly solved by "reading the textbook dup".  In that case, I argued the site, the repository and the user are better off with a specific answer to their problem and not slamma, jamma, close.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - [cont'd] And, a point that seems to be a bit lost here is that when someone is engaged with the OP and is trying to help them clarify or is working with them on a solution, then closing immediately interferes with that effort.  So, active curation (in that circumstance) IS in conflict with someone like me who is engaged and trying to help someone.

Comment: I wouldn't take the votes on this answer as dis/agreement with striving for a **balance**. The answer talks about a lot more things and does not go especially deep into what balance actually means. There's also the practical issue that what people *want* and what they *can have* with the tools available are also two separate things; *wanting* balancing and considering it *feasible* are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - If you don't assign any meaning to the votes on Meta, then what does any of this discussion mean?  Is it just who can respond more often and more forcefully that appears to "win" or "dominate" a discussion?  Are there any employee voices here on Meta who actually speak directly for the company itself (rather than volunteer moderator opinions)?

Comment: I've been wondering if I should do a "who is Meta" post because honestly, I don't really know what anything here on Meta means.  It appears that 95% of "policy" is not written down and is just what the majority of moderators think is the way things should be done.  So, if I come here and question the way things are being done and the dominant voices here are the very moderators behind the way things are being done, then there's not really a whole lot of point in raising a difference of opinion.  By definition, you're kind of swimming upstream.

Comment: @jfriend00 technically, yes, community managers are what connects the company's official stances on matters and the community at large. Their interference in such matters is extremely rare, though.

Comment: @jfriend00 "If you don't assign any meaning to the votes on Meta, then what does any of this discussion mean?" If you just assign whatever meaning *you* think suits *yourself* best, it's equally meaningless. I can personally attest that my lack of agreement is with all the other things aside from **balance**  in the answer.